# FLS Security with ant deployments

Tags: deployment, permissions, ant, fls

Is it correct that ANT defaults FLS to visible? Everywhere else I look it seems to suggest that FLS is only set on profiles that you also have in the package, but that's not what I'm seeing.

FLS for deployed fields seems to be getting set to visible.  This seems true when deploying both entire objects and single custom fields.

Can anyone offer more insight on why this is the case?

Comment: I assume its not for default set .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I wasn't explicitly setting the API in my deployment package.  When I retrieved, Salesforce was automatically updating my deployment package with API 29.0.  I appears that what I was experience was the default behavior until API 30.0.  Updated my deployment API to 33.0 and it now seems to be setting FLS as I'd expect.

[image]

[Documentation Link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm?CSHID=meta_profile.htm#profilefieldlevelsecurity_title)